# Conflicting transaction info on Blockchain.info and Jaxx compared to other sources

Tags: transactions, utxo, payment-batching

I sent a batched transaction with [3 inputs pointing to the same output address](https://blockchain.info/tx/c013927c7879dd24661efb5d495b147ec221353de21d40171df5dfb76c67bbd4). The receiver claims they only received 0.00042 BTC when they should have received a total of 0.00128615 BTC.

She is using the wallet Jaxx which shows the amount received as 0.00042 BTC. Also, the "Estimated BTC Transacted" field on Blockchain.info shows a similar value 0.00042815 BTC.

However, [Block Explorer](https://blockexplorer.com/tx/c013927c7879dd24661efb5d495b147ec221353de21d40171df5dfb76c67bbd4) shows the correct value 0.00128615 BTC.

So is this an issue with how I constructed the transaction or is it simply a display issue in both Blockchain.info and Jaxx?

I suspect that maybe the blockchain explorer is confused by the fact that I batched several different inputs to the same output address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your transaction is fine, and she should have received 0.00128615 BTC.

There is likely some confusion since not only do you have multiple inputs, you also have three outputs going to her address. They add up to 0.00128615 BTC, but each individual output is around 0.00042 BTC. It is possible that Jaxx shows her these as three separate line-items, leading her to believe you only sent 0.0042.

The explorer is not going to be confused by multiple input/outputs, they are a common part of Bitcoin. The estimated BTC transacted about is blockchain.info's best guess at it, and should not be taken as a fact. It is often wrong.